# Content Response Type Image/Png

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to create a aspx page that return `Image/Png` from a `chartDirector`

Here is what I have in my VB so far:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
    Handles Me.Load
    Dim mychart As XYChart = New XYChart(700, 170)
    Dim values As Double() = {25, 18, 15, 12, 8, 30, 35}
    Dim labels As String() = {"Labor", "Licenses", "Taxes", "Legal", "Insurance",
                              "Facilities", "Production"}
    mychart.setPlotArea(30, 20, 200, 200)
    mychart.addBarLayer(values)
    Response.ContentType = "image/png"
    Response.BinaryWrite(mychart.makeChart2(Chart.PNG))
    Response.Close()
End Sub
```

When I run this page I get this output:

> [image]

I got this idea from the following asp code

```vbs
   <%@ language="vbscript" %> 
   <% 
   Set cd = CreateObject("ChartDirector.API") 
   'The data for the bar chart 
   data = Array(85, 156, 179.5, 211, 123) 
   'The labels for the bar chart 
   labels = Array("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri") 
   'First, create a XYChart of size 250 pixels x 250 pixels 
   Set c = cd.XYChart(250, 250) 
   'Set the plotarea rectangle to start at (30, 20) and of  
   322
   '200 pixels in width and 200 in height 
   Call c.setPlotArea(30, 20, 200, 200) 
   'Add a bar chart layer using the supplied data 
   Call c.addBarLayer(data) 
   'Set the x-axis labels using the supplied labels 
   Call c.xAxis().setLabels(labels) 
   'output the chart 
   Response.contenttype = "image/png" 
   Response.binarywrite c.makeChart2(cd.PNG) 
   Response.end 
   %>
```

and it used `img` `src` linked to this page to render the image

*QUESTION* is how can I do the same implementation in `aspx`?

*Notice* I don't know much about .Net I just started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Response.End` instead of `Response.Close`.

The response is buffered, so if you close it the browser doesn't get what's in the buffer unless you flush the buffer before closing the stream.

Answer (score 3):

That's a case where you might want to use a custom `.ashx` HttpHandler rather than a classic `.aspx` page. [Here's](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx) a nice introduction to using these.

Basically you'll inherit the `IHttpHandler` interface, which defines a `ProcessRequest` method. I unfortunately only know C#.

```
public class CustomImageHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        // here you'll use context.Response to set the appropriate
        // content and http headers
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
        byte[] responseImage = GenerateImage();
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(responseImage);
        context.Response.Flush();
    }
}
```